# Creating a snippet and key binding in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext

In sublime I have a snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[<${1:p}>${2:$SELECTION}</${1/([^ ]+).*/$1/}>]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>&lt;</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.xml</scope>
    <description>Long Tag</description>
</snippet>
```

And in .sublime.keymap I have:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+o"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } },
```

Essentially the end-goal is to duplicate this functionality in VS Code. What this does is allow me to press "shift+cmd+o" that triggers the snippet above.

How do I achieve this in VS Code? I tried looking through docs but that is probably a little above my paygrade. I also tried using yo code to point and convert my sublime snippets but it just kept returning "No valid snippets" error when these have been working for years.

Comment: `yo code` is used to convert TextMate stuffs to VSCode. If you can convert Sublime stuffs to TextMate format, then you can convert them via `yo code`.

Comment: Yeah that's also supposed to directly do sublime as well according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/yocode

"Prompts for the folder location that contains TextMate snippets (.tmSnippet) or Sublime snippets (.sublime-snippet). These file are converted to a VS Code snippet file."

Comment: have you updated yocode to latest? They seem to update it recently. If then it still fails to convert you might open an issue on their GitHub repo.